# Jenkins Build rpm sign error

Tags: jenkins, rpm, gpg-agent

I am trying to copy my entire Jenkins configuration from RHEL 6.7 to RHEL 6.9 , On doing this everything looks good, but only one jenkins build is failing with below error

```
Enter pass phrase: 
can't connect to `/usr/share/tomcat6/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or directory
gpg: skipped "Credit": Bad passphrase
gpg: signing failed: Bad passphrase
Pass phrase check failed
```

The gpg private key 1.4.5 exists in jenkins configuration. Strange thing is , all other builds are able to sign rpm but only one build is failing

Anyone know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

RPM reads the passphrase uses getpass(3) and sends to gnupg through an additional file descriptor.

This creates two problems that need to be handled by automating signing mechanisms:

1) Some versions of rpm use getpass(3) which will use a tty (to disable echoing) and will require setting up a pseudo tty so that the automated password can be passed to RPM. Make sure you have the pty file system mounted, and expect(1) is one way to setup the pty from which the password can be read. There's another approach using /proc file descriptors that can be attempted on linux. The password is then sent to gnupg using --passphrase-fd.

2) gnupg2 can also handle persistent passwords in a separate agent process which is sometimes tricky to setup and keep running "automatically" because the detection depends on both the user/process id's. Your report seems to have an agent (which means gnupg2 or special gpg1 configuration) even though you mention 1.4.5 (which would seem to use gnupg1).

Answer (score 0):

I see two separate issues in your log that need to be addressed.

> can't connect to `/usr/share/tomcat6/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file
>   or directory

[gpg-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent) needs to be running as a daemon on the build host, where it will connect to a socket to listen for requests. Perhaps it is already running, but Jenkins is looking for its socket in the wrong directory because `GNUPGHOME` is set to some unusual value. Or perhaps `gpg-agent` isn't running and a new instance needs to be started.

Something like this script can be used to safely attach to an existing `gpg-agent` or spin up a new instance.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Decide whether to start gpg-agent daemon.
# Create necessary symbolic link in $GNUPGHOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent

SOCKET=S.gpg-agent
PIDOF=`pgrep gpg-agent`
RETVAL=$?

if [ "$RETVAL" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Starting gpg-agent daemon."
    eval `gpg-agent --daemon `
else
    echo "Daemon gpg-agent already running."
fi

# Nasty way to find gpg-agent's socket file...
GPG_SOCKET_FILE=`find /tmp/gpg-* -name $SOCKET`
echo "Updating socket file link."
cp -fs $GPG_SOCKET_FILE $GNUPGHOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
```

You may want to substitute `pgrep` for `pidof`, depending on your shell.

If you do end up starting a new agent, you can check to see that your keys have been loaded into it by running `gpg --list-keys`. If you don't see it listed, you'll need to add it using `gpg --import`. Follow the Jenkins docs for [Using Credentials](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/).

Resolving the `gpg-agent` issue may resolve your other issue, so check to see if your job is working before doing anything else.

References:

- [www.linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/gpg-gpg-agent-can%27t-connect-to-root-gnupg-s-gpg-agent-611843/#post3485213)

> gpg: skipped "Credit": Bad passphrase

The GPG key is protected by a passphrase. `rpm` is asking for this passphrase and expects it to be manually entered. Of course, Jenkins is running things non-interactively, so that's not going to be possible. We need some way to supply the passphrase to `rpm` so it can forward it along to `gpg`, or else we need to supply the passphrase to `gpg` directly via some sort of caching mechanism.

**The Expect Method**

By wrapping our `rpm --addsign` call in an [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script, we can use `expect` to enter the passphrase headlessly. This practice is fairly common. Assuming the following script named `rpm_sign.exp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set password [lindex $argv 0]
set files [lrange $argv 1 1]
spawn rpm --define --addsign $files
expect "Enter pass phrase:"
send -- "$password\r"
expect eof
```

This script can be used in a Jenkins shell step or pipeline as follows:

```
echo "Signing rpms ..."
sh "./rpm_sign.exp '${GPG_PASSPHRASE}' <list-of-files>"
```

Please note that, with some modifications, it is possible to specify which GPG identity you want to sign your RPMs with. This is done by passing `--define {_gpg_name $YOUR_KEY_ID_HERE}` as an argument to rpm inside the wrapper script. Note the [TCL](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html) syntax. Since we're doing this on Jenkins, which may offer multiple sets of credentials, I assume this is relevant info.

References:

- [aaronhawley.livejournal.com](https://aaronhawley.livejournal.com/10615.html)
- [lists.fedoraproject.org](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/NDF6TIMXKZTBH5H4CGYQEJTHF5Y5BHZY/)

**Other Methods**

There are other solutions out there that may be more appropriate to your configuration. One such solution is to use [RpmSignPlugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/rpmsign-plugin), which uses `expect` under the hood. Other solutions can be found in this posting on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328601/rpmsign-with-cli-password-prompt).